# python beautifulsoup find between tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to get data from a website. I managed to get a subset of the data I want

```
sections = rows.findAll('p')
for section in sections
    print section
```

Which gives me this:

```
<p><i>Hello<strong>World</strong></i></p>
<p><strong>Some Text</strong><p>
<p></p>
<p><strong>Monday</strong><p>
<p>section1</p>
<p>section2</p>
<p>section3</p>
<p><strong>Tuesday</strong><p>
<p>section1</p>
<p>section2</p>
<p>section3</p>
<p>section4</p>
<p></p>
```

What I want is this:

```
Monday
section1
section2
section3
Tuesday
section1
section2
section3
section4
```

Can I get all the p tags between the strong tags if strong is equal to a dict I have? Or how should I solve it?

Comment: what was original HTML ?  Where in HTML do you have these `<p>` ? Maybe they are in some unique tag which you could use to filter results - ie `find("some tag", "attributes").find_all("p")`

Comment: maybe slice results `rows.findAll('p')[3:-1]`

Comment: The original html is a mess but all p tags are located in a div  `code`  rows = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'box-default top-border'})

Comment: can't you show url for this page?

Comment: Sure. This is the page. Its in swedish an in my example I tried to simplify it https://westmanska.se/dagens-lunch/

Comment: it seems you need all `<p>` after `Vecka 10` which is in `<h1>` and it is unique tag which you could try to use to filter data.

Comment: BTW: you should add link to question and other users will see it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use regex module and then replace the for loop with below code snippet. It will do the work

```
import re
# your code
for section in sections 
    match=re.match(r'^(?:\s*<[^>]*?>\s*)*?([^<>]+?)(?:\s*<[^>]*?>\s*)*?$',section)
    if(match):
        print(match.group(1))
```

In case if you want to know what the regex matches:

^(?:\s*<[^>]*?>\s*)*?:
    Will match multiple tags from start of the string

([^<>]+?):
    Will group words in between the starting and ending tags

(?:\s*<[^>]*?>\s*)*?$:
    Will match multiple tags till the end of the string

Comment: The problem is that it can be whatever in the p tag. I just took section1, section2 etc as an example which was not the best I guess

Comment: @Ruud you should show real HTML which you have and then we can try create code for this real HTML. Now we can work only with this what HTML you show in question because we don't have idea how complex can be your HTML.

Comment: BTW: in comment below question OP added url to original HTML: https://westmanska.se/dagens-lunch/

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

data = requests.post('https://westmanska.se/dagens-lunch/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, features="html5lib")
status = False
for div_tag in soup.find_all('div', class_="box-default top-border"):
    if div_tag.find_next('h5'):
        for p_tag in div_tag.find_all('p'):
            if not p_tag.find_next('i') or not p_tag.find_next('br'):
                    print(p_tag.text)
```

Comment: your code gives `HelloWorld` and `Some Text` but OP doesn't want it.

Comment: Change for loop **for p_tag in soup.find_all('p')[2:]:** @furas

Comment: you could add it in answer. But in other comments you can read that OP has more complex HTML (but OP didn't show it) and it may need more complex solution :)

Comment: BTW: in comment below question OP added url to original HTML: https://westmanska.se/dagens-lunch/

Comment: @furas I have updated code based on website use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict to save your data and to check what to save. Current group is always saves in `current_group`, simple logic:

```
needed_sections_dict = {'Monday': [], 'Tuesday': []}
current_group = None

sections = rows.findAll('p')
for section in sections
    # check if current p contains strong group heading
    # change current_group and continue if it found
    group = section.find('strong')
    if group and group.text:
        if group.text in needed_sections_dict:
            current_group = group.text
        else:
            # not needed group
            current_group = None
        continue

    # current section is not <strong>
    # so we check that it contains something and add it to
    # current group dict list if current_group is not None (needed)
    if current_group and section.text.strip():
        needed_sections_dict[current_group].append(section.text)
```

Test:

```
>>> needed_sections_dict
{'Monday': ['section1', 'section2', 'section3'],
 'Tuesday': ['section1', 'section2', 'section3', 'section4']}
```

Comment: BTW: in comment below question OP added url to original HTML: https://westmanska.se/dagens-lunch/

Answer (score 0):

It seem in https://westmanska.se/dagens-lunch/ you need all `<p>` after `Vecka 10` which is in `<h1>` and it is unique tag which you can try to use to filter data.

```
soup.find('h1').find_next_siblings('p'):
```

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://westmanska.se/dagens-lunch/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.find('h1').find_next_siblings('p'):
    print(row.text)
```

Result:

```
Måndag
Currystekt kycklingfilé med mangosås & grönsaksris (GF/LF)
Rödbetsgravad lax med stuvade gulbetor & potatis serveras med gröna ärtor & citron (GF/LF)
Falafel med tahinisås, grönsaksris & saltgurka (GF)
Capresesoppa med soltorkade tomater, oregano, basilika & mozzarella (LF/Vegan utan ost)
Pasta bolognese med rökt sidfläsk & champinjoner toppas med parmesanost samt ruccola (LF)
Tisdag
Raggmunk med stekt fläsk & rårörda lingon (GF/LF)
Posherad torskrygg med gräslökssås, kokt potatis, pepparrot & bacon (GF/LF)
Kikärtsplättar med rostade nötter, friterad chevré, färsk fikon & saffranshonung
Capresesoppa med soltorkade tomater, oregano, basilika & mozzarella (LF/Vegan utan ost)
Pasta bolognese med rökt sidfläsk & champinjoner toppas med parmesanost samt ruccola (LF)
Onsdag
Pannbiff med grönpepparsås, potatismos & rårörda lingon
Ugnsbakad koljafilé med äggsås, dillslungad potatis & riven morot (GF/LF)
Majsplättar med avokado-chimmichurri & kokt potatis(GF/Vegan)
Capresesoppa med soltorkade tomater, oregano, basilika & mozzarella (LF/Vegan utan ost)
Pasta bolognese med rökt sidfläsk & champinjoner toppas med parmesanost samt ruccola (LF)
 
Torsdag (Stängt fullbokat)
 
Fredag 
Örtmarinerad flankstek med rödvinsås, potatisgratäng & ångad broccoli (GF/LF)
Panerad flundra med curryremoulad, kokt potatis, gröna ärtor & citron (LF)
Bakad sötpotatis med avokado/fetaoströra toppas med picklad rödlök & lime (GF)
Capresesoppa med soltorkade tomater, oregano, basilika & mozzarella (LF/Vegan utan ost)
Pasta bolognese med rökt sidfläsk & champinjoner toppas med parmesanost samt ruccola (LF)
```